# how change selectedItem in vaadin-combo-box in polymer programmatically

Tags: combobox, polymer, vaadin, selecteditem

I have a question in polymer

```js
valueCategoryChange: function() {
  this.set("mycategory", this.$.comboCategory.selectedItem);
},
```

```html
<vaadin-combo-box on-value-changed="valueCategoryChange" id="comboCategory" items="{{categories}}" item-value-path="id" value="{{category22}}" item-label-path="display" required>
```

if I select from combobox everything work well and `valueCategoryChange()`
shows selectedItem.
but when I select an item in combobox programmatically from value
`this.category22 = data.CatId;` ,that item is shown in combobox but in `valueCategoryChange` function, `this.$.comboCategory.selectedItem` is `null`
please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you use like below:

```
<vaadin-combo-box selected-item="{{mycategory}}" id="comboCategory" items="{{categories}}" item-value-path="id" value="{{category22}}" item-label-path="display" required>
<div> Selected Item is [[mycategory]]</div>
```

then you will have a selected item property as  `mycategory`. Also you will not need a `valueCategoryChange` function and `on-value-changed="valueCategoryChange"` event. 
Beside this if you need to set event and want to use the functions than you can use:

```
valueCategoryChange: function() {
  console.log(this.mycategory);  // is the selected item that you can use 
  // this.set("mycategory", this.mycategory)  will not be useful :)) 
},
```

(Run below code snipped) or  [DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/YBrXYo?editors=1011)

```js
    HTMLImports.whenReady( ()=> {
      
    class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'x-foo';
        }
    
    }
    window.customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo)

    })
```

```html
    <head>
      <script
      
      <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/">
      <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
      
      <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn-origin.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-combo-box/vaadin-combo-box.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn-origin.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-grid/all-imports.html">
     
    </head>

    <body>
    <x-foo id="xfoo"items="{{categories}}"></data-table-d>
      
    <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>

    <vaadin-combo-box selected-item="{{mycategory}}" id="comboCategory" items="{{categories}}" value="{{category22}}" ></vaadin-combo-box><br><br>
    <div> Selected Item is [[mycategory]]</div>

      <script>
        var el = document.getElementById('xfoo');
        el.categories=['Cat1', 'Cat2','Cat3'];
      
      </script>
    </template>
    </dom-module>
```